# Linear transformations and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a question from Linear Algebra an introductory approach:

> Prove that $\operatorname{dim}T(V) = \operatorname{rank}A$, where $A$ is the matrix of $T$ belonging to $L(V, V)$ with respect to an arbitrary basis of $V$.

hope someone can help Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\dim V=n$ and $E=\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n\}$ is the basis of $A$ such that the matrix of $T$ with respect to $E$ is $A$.
Then (why?):
$$\dim T(V)=\dim\{T(e_1),T(e_2),\ldots,T(e_n)\}=\dim\{Ae_1,Ae_2,\ldots,Ae_n\}=\\\dim\{\text{space spanned by the columns of }A\}.$$
What is your definition of $\operatorname{rank}(A)$?

Comment: rank (A) is one

Comment: @megan: What do you mean $\operatorname{rank}(A)$ is one?

Comment: the dim(T(V))=rank(A)